# Adding dynamically to an empty string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to assign each character in a nonempty string to an empty string (making a copy). Here is my code:

```
x = "example";
y = "";

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    y.charAt(i) = x.charAt(i);
}

alert(y);
```

However, I get the following error in the console:

```
ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
y.charAt(i) = x.charAt(i);
```

I thought it was possible to grow a non-empty string dynamically (hope i'm using the correct terminology). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: *Only* variables and properties (or more strictly speaking, ReferenceSpecificationTypes) may appear on the "left-hand side" of an `=`. A function can *never* appear on the left of an `=`. Anyway, strings are immutable, so create a new string based off the old. You likely want `str + str` here.

Answer (score 0):

The `"".charAt(0)` in an empty string is not defined. Indeed, `"a".charAt(0)` is "a".

Why don't you concatenate?

```
x = "example";
y = "";

//Simplest way:
y += x;

//With characters:
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    y += x.charAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`charAt(x)` returns a string containing a character at the position `x` of the string `this`, but does not return a **link** to that position, thus, it is not equal to C's `[]` notation which returns a link to a byte where the character is located.
So, the `charAt(x)=` assignment is not valid as well as `"a"="b"` isn't, too.

Anyway, you can't do `"".charAt(x)` no matter what is `x`, because the string is empty.

Anyway, you can't even do `"a".charAt(0)="b"`, because of the reason described in the first paragraph.

So, the only way to **change** some character in a string is `str[x]`, which works in most browsers. But you still can't `""[0]"`, so you should first create a string with the same length as the string you are copying, or use concatenation.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible. This is the right way to go:

```
x = "example";  
y = "";

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    y += x.charAt(i);
}
```

Your approach is not correct, since the **charAt(i)** method returns the (read-only) value of the char at position i.

Instead, an **assignment operator**, such as `=`, stores the value on the right side of the op `=` into the variable on the left side.

In this case `y += x.charAt(i)` is equal to `y = y + x.charAt(i)`.

e.g.:

*1st iteration:*

```
x = "example";
y = ""

i = 0
x.charAt(i) == x.charAt(0) == "e"
y += x.charAt(i) -> y = y + x.charAt(i) -> y = y + x.charAt(0) -> y = y + "e" -> y = "" + "e" = e
```

*2nd iteration:*

```
x = "example";
y = "e"

i = 1
x.charAt(i) == x.charAt(1) == "x"
y += x.charAt(i) -> y = y + x.charAt(i) -> y = y + x.charAt(1) -> y = y + "x" -> y = "e" + "x"
```

and so on...

At each step, the **char** at position i of of the string x is appended to the string y and in the end `x === y`.

Comment: Would this create a new string object with each += since strings are immutable? That wouldn't be "dynamicaly grown string" that OP wants

Comment: Why not just do `y=x;` if that's what you are doing?